Using grafana operator, how can I create an Opensearch DataSource and set withCredentials = true in the Yaml?
I am using grafana operator to setup an Opensearch Datasource. According to the api documentation, the field cannot be set under the spec like this :
apiVersion: grafana.integreatly.org/v1beta1
kind: GrafanaDatasource
spec:
  datasource:
    withCredentials: true

But if you inspect the Datasource configuration page when clicking Save & Test you can see this withCredentials field :

I've tried to put it in the jsonData (see the screen) and secureJsonData (gives me an error) to see if would be taken into account but it doesn´t :
apiVersion: grafana.integreatly.org/v1beta1
kind: GrafanaDatasource
spec:
  datasource:
    jsonData:
      withCredentials: true

apiVersion: grafana.integreatly.org/v1beta1
kind: GrafanaDatasource
spec:
  datasource:
    secureJsonData:
      withCredentials: true

Does anyone knows how to set this field to true using grafana operator ?

Perhaps this can help, try it out.
apiVersion: grafana.integreatly.org/v1beta1
kind: GrafanaDatasource
spec:
  valuesFrom:
    - targetPath: "basicAuthUser"
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: "grafana-opensearch-secrets"
          key: "OPENSEARCH_USERNAME"
    - targetPath: "secureJsonData.basicAuthPassword"
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: "grafana-opensearch-secrets"
          key: "OPENSEARCH_PASSWORD"
  datasource:
    basicAuthUser: ${OPENSEARCH_USERNAME}
    securejsonData:
      "basicAuthPassword": ${OPENSEARCH_PASSWORD}

